# How do we find which customers placed orders with items made in USA refer to image

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

Which customers placed orders with items made inside the USA?

SELECT DISTINCT, WHERE, Temporary Table, Subquery

tables to refer

[image]

Comment: With the data you have available, you can't guarantee that any item was *made* in the USA, only that the supplier is *based* in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `exists` with a correlated subquery that follows the relationships like customer > order > order_item > product > supplier and filters on US suppliers:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where exists (
    select 1
    from order o
    inner join order_item oi on oi.order_id = o.id
    inner join product p on p.id = oi.product_id
    inner join supplier s on s.id = p.supplier_id
    where o.customer_id = c.id and s.country = 'USA'
)
```